# Can't debug Maui project with target project as Windows

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I've tested out my Maui project on Android and it works perfectly fine.

Now, I've been trying to test it out on Windows, but as soon as I start the application, the application closes. The output log also shows `2147942405` exit code. I've tried to run the application as admin and I've also opened up Visual Studio as admin but it's not been a help.

Is there something else I should do?

Comment: When was the last time you updated your VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, did you try to create a new maui project and debug it on the windows? In addition, is your pc's system windows 10? If so, it seems an existed issue which is about [MAUI apps crash on launch on Windows after Visual Studio update - code 2147942405](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080) on the github.

And you can try the workaround in this issue which tried to [download the Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Redist.1.2.zip and run its WindowsAppRuntimeInstall.exe (as admin)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080#issuecomment-1358398569) .

Finally, you can follow up this issue on the github.

Comment: Thank you. Installing https://aka.ms/windowsappsdk/1.2/latest/windowsappruntimeinstall-x64.exe fixed the problem.