# MAUI app hangs while I am trying to run it

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui, maui-windows

I am starting maui app in Visual Studio using button "Windows Machine" and the result is on the picture that I connetced. Is it a problem in Visual Studio? I asked my college to check an app on his pc and he showed me that it wors and launches without hanging...

I tried to change text property of the area it works perfectly

Comment: Here is the screenshot of running maui app - https://files.fm/f/3zntkbgjh

Comment: Do you have this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads Installed? Also, do you run it as Administrator?

Comment: Try to delete ./bin and ./obj folder of your project (may need to close visual studio) and restart the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't debug Maui project with target project as Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959038/cant-debug-maui-project-with-target-project-as-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps below:

1. open Computer Settings→ select Privacy & Security→ select Turn on developer mode.
2. [downloads for the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads).
3. delete the 'bin' and 'obj' folders, rebuild and run your project.